# iOS. get other device/computer name by IP in the same local network

Tags: ios, cocoa, networking, lan

One task of my program is to scan local wi-fi network for any devices/computers in same network. I found solution to get all working devices IPs, but did not managed to get names of them. I did not find any clue to solve this problem.
Any suggestions?

Comment: How did you get the list of all working devices? what was the code used for scanning. I tried whole lot of code from the internet but couldnt acheive this @Nikolay Shubenkov

Comment: Detect your IP. I your IP is, for example 192.168.2.44, then ping all IPs with addresses from 192.168.2.1 to 192.168.2.255. if you need code, create question on StackOverflow, post link to that question and I will post project to github and put a link to that project in answer to your question.

Comment: Here is the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29545847/cfhoststartinforesolution-fails-get-device-name-from-ip-address-on-lan) to that question.  @Nikolay Shubenkov

Comment: @NikolayShubenkov you got succeed for get computer name from IP address ?

Comment: Unfortunately no. At least now. This is quite old question and I can not recheck this as project with code just do not compiles.

Comment: Had any one get succeed to fetch hostname?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to perform a reverse DNS lookup, you need to call the `CFHostGetNames` function, like this:

```
+ (NSArray *)hostnamesForIPv4Address:(NSString *)address
{
    struct addrinfo *result = NULL;
    struct addrinfo hints;

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_flags = AI_NUMERICHOST;
    hints.ai_family = PF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = 0;

    int errorStatus = getaddrinfo([address cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding], NULL, &hints, &result);
    if (errorStatus != 0) {
        return nil;
    }

    CFDataRef addressRef = CFDataCreate(NULL, (UInt8 *)result->ai_addr, result->ai_addrlen);
    if (addressRef == nil) {
        return nil;
    }
    freeaddrinfo(result);

    CFHostRef hostRef = CFHostCreateWithAddress(kCFAllocatorDefault, addressRef);
    if (hostRef == nil) {
        return nil;
    }
    CFRelease(addressRef);

    BOOL succeeded = CFHostStartInfoResolution(hostRef, kCFHostNames, NULL);
    if (!succeeded) {
        return nil;
    }

    NSMutableArray *hostnames = [NSMutableArray array];

    CFArrayRef hostnamesRef = CFHostGetNames(hostRef, NULL);
    for (int currentIndex = 0; currentIndex < [(__bridge NSArray *)hostnamesRef count]; currentIndex++) {
        [hostnames addObject:[(__bridge NSArray *)hostnamesRef objectAtIndex:currentIndex]];
    }

    return hostnames;
}
```

Comment: i tried your code but i am always getting null value from that function. I am trying to get computer name in iOS app.Can you please suggest me right way to found computer name. Thanks

Comment: above function fail to get hostname for some network at this point and return null .   BOOL succeeded = CFHostStartInfoResolution(hostRef, kCFHostNames, NULL);
    if (!succeeded) {
        return nil;
    } . any idea why

Answer (score 0):

`BOOL succeeded = CFHostStartInfoResolution(hostRef, kCFHostNames, NULL);` Now I encounter that always failed at this line, and I tried to use `getnameinfo` function, it is still can't get the hostname

Answer (score 0):

Swift Edition of @neilco answer.

```
class HostnameConverter {
    
    static func hostnames(forIPv4Address address: String) -> [String]? {
        var result: UnsafeMutablePointer<addrinfo>?
        var hints = addrinfo()
        memset(&hints, 0, MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: hints))
        hints.ai_flags = AI_NUMERICHOST
        hints.ai_family = PF_UNSPEC
        hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM
        hints.ai_protocol = 0
        
        let errorStatus = getaddrinfo(address, nil, &hints, &result)
        guard errorStatus == 0 else {
            return nil
        }
        defer {
            freeaddrinfo(result)
        }
        
        guard let ai_addr = result?.pointee.ai_addr,
              let ai_addrlen = result?.pointee.ai_addrlen,
              let addressRef = CFDataCreate(nil, ai_addr, numericCast(ai_addrlen))
        else {
            return nil
        }
        
        let hostRef = CFHostCreateWithAddress(nil, addressRef)
        
        let succeeded = CFHostStartInfoResolution(hostRef.takeUnretainedValue(), .names, nil)
        guard succeeded else {
            return nil
        }
        
        var hostnames = [String]()
        if let hostnamesRef = CFHostGetNames(hostRef.takeUnretainedValue(), nil) {
            for currentIndex in 0..<CFArrayGetCount(hostnamesRef.takeUnretainedValue()) {
                let cfString = unsafeBitCast(CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(hostnamesRef.takeUnretainedValue(), currentIndex), to: CFString.self)
                let hostname = String(cfString)
                hostnames.append(hostname)
            }
        }
        
        return hostnames
    }
}
```