# Host name getting empty on specific networks

Tags: ios, swift

I am using [MMLanScan](https://github.com/mavris/MMLanScan) to scan network to get connected devices to wifi.It works fine but sometime it return hostName empty on some specific network.Screen shoot with [Hostname](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmXxZ.png) and [WithoutHostName](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jscHh.png) .how can i solve this?. I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19376123/ios-get-other-device-computer-name-by-ip-in-the-same-local-network?rq=1) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25992989/how-to-get-the-other-devices-host-name-in-the-same-wifi?rq=1) link also but these solution have also same issue to return null host name for some Internets connections.Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Before going to down vote my question please give me a reason so that i can improve my question.

Comment: Did you find any solution?